# How to check wordpress plugin written in php/javascript for suspicious code or bad requests?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am buying a wordpress plugin and it has php/javascript/css/json files.
I need to check the plugin so after paying for it, it won't be tempered with or terminated by the original programmer (freelancer) after a while.
Is there any specific codes that might send and recieve permission to run the code from outside the domain?

Comment: There is a lot of ways that someone could make a WordPress plugin that automatically “breaks” in the future. Time-based kill switches, remote query ones, magic URL back doors, special request headers,  third party libraries, and all this can even be encoded or obfuscated code. If you don’t trust this programmer, don’t use their code, or get it audited by another programmer.

Comment: You can have vulnerabilities even in top plugins. Also one time coded plugin will never last long since the system is changing all the time. Could be 10 years could be a month before breaking depending on what is changed. Consider developers with support.

Comment: Like @ChrisHaas said if you dont trust the dev dont install it. Its the same with any other plugin out there.

Comment: its very necessary plugin for me, can't be replaced.
the problem is that I had a little fued with the freelancer, and I need a way to check the code, the code is not big, would you recommend to be audited by another freelancer or is there a list of php codes that indicate that the code could be compromised?